# Maven Build Cache Extension keep running surefire:test and failsafe:integration-test even without any code change

Tags: maven

I'm trying to configure maven-build-cache-extension plugin onto my multi-module project using default cache configuration.

First run is as usually long (about 40 mins). However the next run even without any code change, is still taking long time (about 36 mins). Upon closer look, maven is still running all the surefire:test and failsafe:integration-test goals.

What would be the correct configuration to skip those goals if no change in the code?

Comment: If you see that the tests are rerunning, then the build cache is not initialized, or the next run has inconsistencies with the previous runs, so the cache is not reusable. That could happen for many reasons, and the cache guide describes the most common of them. You must first configure the cache as described in the guide. Out-of-the-box default config doesn’t guarantee reliable caching.

Answer (score 2):

The build log would be much helpful.

The most proven way to check why checksum is different between builds is to compare 'buildinfo' files. With local cache it can be found at .m2/cache.
Looks like in your case there are 2 build info files with different checksum from build #1 and build #2. Please check the 'projectsInputInfo' to see where is the diff.

The initial build cache tuning requires some effort, as it's not possible to consider every specific configuration. Here is an example why caching didn't work out of the box https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MBUILDCACHE/issues/MBUILDCACHE-47

Answer (score -2):

The concept is to do compilation on code-changes.

If there is no code changes, Maven will still execute the tests.
There is no flag to change this behaviour.

Perhaps you should consider running the integration tests separately so your flow will not be interrupted while developing (Usually in the build-server, e.g. merge-requests, nightly builds).

The ordinary unit-tests should not take too long by any means, if it takes longer than a second, it is too slow to run in dev-env.

Comment: idea about skipping tests is obvious, however [extension developers promise to reduce testing time as well](https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/): "Speedup developer builds. By reusing cached builds developers could verify changes much faster and be more productive. No more -DskipTests and similar."

Comment: I agree with @AndreyB.Panfilov. I literally finish my build (that include test), no change to any file and re-run the exact same maven command. It rebuild and rerun the test.

Comment: So perhaps the cache is not working well after all. If the extension would find a cache that matches, it should neither execute any build goals, such as compile. With information provided it can't be guessed what is wrong. Do you have prove of cache re-use?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. It turns out it's maven jacoco plugin that force everything to be recompiled and re-tested. Without it, locally it doesn't rerun the compile & test. However in Jenkins, somehow a particular module is always having cache missed and rebuild. That module has wsdl that is being rebuild (but somehow locally it doesn't get rebuild).

Comment: Looks like you nailed it :) Would be good if you could answer your question then.